# Laravel - Get info about user via ID from relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I've a three tables: for tickets, replies from ticket and with users. I want get ticket with replies from it and data about respondent. My tables looks something like this:

User:

```
ID | Username | Email | ...
```

Tickets:

```
ID | title | user_id | active | ...
```

Tickets_Replies:

```
ID | tickets_id | message | user_id | ...
```

How it should look in Eloquent ORM? At this moment I've

User:

```
<?php
class User extends Eloquent {    
public function replies() {
    return $this->belongsTo("Tickets_Replies");
}
}
?>
```

Tickets_Replies:

```
<?php
class Tickets_Replies extends Eloquent {    
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Tickets');
    }
}
?>
```

And Tickets:

```
<?php

class Tickets extends Eloquent {    
    public function replies() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough("Tickets_Replies", "User");
    }
}
?>
```

I've bug somewhere because search "tickets_id" column un Users Table. How can I fix this?

In SQL Query it should looks:

```
select `tickets_replies`.*, `users`.`username` 
from `tickets_replies` 
left join `users` 
    on `users`.`id` = `tickets_replies`.`user_id` 
where `tickets_replies`.tickets_id = [TICKET_ID]
```

Comment: What kind of query you want ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera I added SQL Query to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your table names to users, tickets and ticketreplies. That's the best practices for laravel and the way i've setup your relationships below:

**User:**

```
<?php
    class User extends Eloquent {

        public function tickets() {
            return $this->hasMany('Ticket');
        }

        public function replies() {
            return $this->hasMany('TicketReply');
        }

    }
?>
```

**TicketReply:**

```
<?php
    class TicketReply extends Eloquent {

        protected $table = 'ticketreplies';

        public function ticket()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('Tickets');
        }

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('User');
        }

    }
?>
```

**Ticket:**

```
<?php

    class Ticket extends Eloquent {  

        public function replies() {
            return $this->hasMany('TicketReply');
        }

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('User');
        }

    }

?>
```

**How to get your data:**

```
<?php
    Ticket::with('replies', 'replies.user')->find('id of ticket here');
?>
```

That will get you a Ticket model with the nested relationships you asked for. (:

Comment: How can I show username in view? I've foreach for `$ticket->replies` as `$reply` and I'm looking something in `$reply->user` but I don't really know what now...

Comment: {{ $reply->user->username }} simple as that ;)

Comment: If you're in doubt you can always do a var_dump. Theres a nice little helper function in laravel dd() (short for die and dump). dd($reply->user) !

Comment: I know. I just do a little mistake and for one reply i add user_id as 0 <facepalm>. Thank you anyway for help. It works! :)